# How do I refactor resource filenames in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have resource files in my package structure.  For example, like this:

```
com/mywebsite/myapp/myimage.png
```

And in my code I read the file like so:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myimage.png");
```

I want to change the name of `myimage.png`.  How can I do this and have it update the references in code as well?  I tried Refactor > Rename in Package Explorer, but it did not update the code.  Is there a convenient way to do this that does not involve find/copy/replace?

Comment: use find and replace feature of eclipse and you can also choose the file type in which you want to search and replace, It will search in whole project and will change recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not have deep enough knowledge of your source to facilitate this kind of refactoring.

You may want to consider placing your resource "next to" the class using it, and then use relative paths to refer to it.  You will still need to move the resources manually after you refactor your classes, but it is still better than simply using search and replace.

I have frequently heard that IntelliJ have deeper understanding of your source tree than other IDE's, so it might be able to do this.

Comment: Yes, in Android Studio/IntelliJ this would have definitely worked.